# set the default option on page load

Tags: html, material-design

I need to set an option as a default value of that dropdown while loading the page. I'm using Material design dropdowns. I tried the following code. But it isn't working with material design. Please Help.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group label-floating float-label-control" id="select-field">
        <div class="float-label-control">
            <label class="control-label">Country
                <small>(required)</small>
            </label>
        </div>
        <select class=" dropdown" id="country">
            <option>BCT Dubai</option>
            <option selected="selected">BCT India</option>
            <option>BCT Muscat</option>
            <option>BCT QFC</option>
            <option>BCT Singapore</option>
            <option>BCT TAIWAN</option>
            <option>BCT US</option>
            <option>BRUNEIEI</option>
            <option>SAUDI</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected try here

Comment: @Er.Er It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'selected' attribute as follows.

```
<option selected="selected" selected>BCT India</option>
```

OR

just keep as

```
  <option  selected>BCT India</option>
```

Codepen example is here https://codepen.io/etcpe9/pen/PqyOye/

Comment: This is working when i am using normal dropdown. But with material design it's not working